# Exporting a PDF from QGIS Print Composer for Avenza Pdf Maps

Tags: qgis, print-composer, printing, geopdf, avenza

Alright I actually did this successfully a few months back following these steps http://www.avenza.com/resources/blog/2016/12/06/exporting-qgis-avenza-maps.

Now when I bring the map into Avenza, I get a "Map Not Referenced"

Now I have no clue what I am doing wrong.  I have tried and tried.  I have unistalled and reinstalled.  Tried to export as image then convert format.

A strange thing to note, I can not select reference map under Print Composer-> Export Settings -> Reference Map.

Comment: What version of QGIS are you using? If possible, are you able to email us at support@avenza.com and send us the document you are working with within QGIS so that I can take a better look at it? Thank you, Kate Avenza Support

Comment: I noticed the same behaviour on 2.18.10 so I filed a bug report to help get it investigated https://issues.qgis.org/issues/16796

Comment: I am using version 2.18.10.  I was able successfully able to export a Pdf for avenza.  If I had to guess, I think that my problem has to do something with QGIS not being completely uninstalled.  I believe that since I have had multiple versions of QGIS on my computer, I am not able to "Reference the Map."  I have noticed that on other versions of QGIS, as soon as I draw a rectangle to "add map," that "Map 0" would instantly appear.  Now it doesn't.  In summary, I think that my issue has to do with doing the advanced install, or having bits f older QGIS floating around in my registry.

Comment: According to the comments in https://issues.qgis.org/issues/16796, the dropdown field in QGIS 2.18.10 is empty if you only have one map. This behaviour was different in QGIS 2.18.4. Not sure if this has any impact on the avenza workflow.

Comment: @AndreJ thanks a lot.  It appears that 2.18.4 is the answer to question.  I will follow up on this tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Using QGIS 2.18.13 installed using network installer I was able to export my Print Composer map to a geoPDF that is recognized by Avenza 2.3.x as georeferenced.  When in Print Composer I select the Composition tab, and in Export Settings set the Reference Map as the selected map, e.g. Map 0.  Then export as a PDF.