# OSGEO Advanced Install Problems with Print Composer

Tags: qgis, installation, print-composer, printing

I would like to have the ability to read/write file gdb data and export my data as a GEOpdf. I have always done the advanced install option so that I can read/write file gdb data.  However, now I need to get version 2.18, so that I can export geopdf from print composer.

My problem is that when installing the advanced option, I am forced to install the LTR version 2.14.16 due to some dependencies for different plug ins such as grass, etc.  This creates a problem in that when I go to create a map (in version 2.18), I do not have the ability to reference it in the Print Composer options. Or when I create in a map in 2.14.16, I do not have the ability to georeference.

Any Ideas out there

Comment: So I have continued to work on this.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled QGIS several times.  If I do a basic install, I have the ability to create a GEOpdf.  If I go advanced install option via OSGEO, I have the ability to read write File Gdb.

Comment: It should be possible to install qgis and qgis-ltr in parallel with OSGEO4W setup. If you have trouble with OSGEO4W setup, you can try the standalone installer (but without filegdb). Both installations can run in parallel.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have not had a problem with installing them in parallel.  My problem is that I can not Print Composer-> Export Settings -> Reference Map. As stated in this tutorial.
http://www.avenza.com/resources/blog/2016/12/06/exporting-qgis-avenza-maps.  I have another similar question posted as well.

Comment: I think you should leave the print compser issue with https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/246390/exporting-a-pdf-from-qgis-print-composer-for-avenza-pdf-maps. The OSGEO4W setup offers package `qgis` 2.18.9 and 2.18.10, and `qgis-ltr`  2.14.15 and 2.14.16. If you select `gdal-filegdb`, both will have fileGDB support (which standalone does not have).